# Convert formated TXT file to JSON using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, file, ruby-on-rails-4

What's the best way to parse a text file with the following format, to JSON, or a faster way of getting the key/value from the file?

```
Data Format: 
  dateTimeDelimiter: " "
  decimalSeparator: "."
  dataDelimiter: ","
  dateFormat: M/d/yy
  timeFormat: HH:mm:ss
  gmtOffset: "-5"
  daylightSavings: true

Logger Info: 
  - &1
  launchDescription: "DESCr"
  model: U30
  vendor: VendorName
  serialNumber: 1234567
  memorySize: 0
  firmwareVersion: 1.117
  firmwareVersionRaw: 0
  deploymentNumber: 1523
Series Info: 
 - name: "Scaled Series"
   type: value
   unitName: "kW"
   OMClassName: OMeasurementH21
   OMPartNumber: S-UCD-MXXX
   OMUnitIndex: 0
   OMChannelType: 12
   OMValuePattern: "#,##0.;-#,##0."
   logger: *1
 - name: "Scaled Series"
   type: value
   unitName: "kW"
   OMClassName: OMeasurementH21
   OMPartNumber: S-UCD-MXXX
   OMUnitIndex: 0
   OMChannelType: 12
   OMValuePattern: "#,##0.;-#,##0."
   logger: *1

   ----
```

After the dotted line there is CSV data that I'm already parsing.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file looks like YAML.  You should be able to parse it to a hash using `yaml = YAML.load_file("some_file.txt")` and then convert it to JSON with `yaml.to_json`

Comment: Did you try this? It does not work when I try it here. `Psych::SyntaxError: (input.yaml): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 11 column 3`. I'm not familiar with YAML, but it seems this is not valid YAML.

Comment: :D you rock!... just one quick question: How can I parse till it the "-----" line?

Comment: We don't parse `---` lines, the YAML parser handles them for us. That looks like a document separator in YAML that was accidentally indented. Read [the YAML documentation](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html).

Comment: @theTinMan I mean the file have CSV data below the dashed line, I want to get the YAML part of the file to JSON.